# Identifying arrays

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a vast question in regards to logic. I'm working on a project that is suppose to teach me inheritance. I have a super class named bankaccount, and extended from that a checking and savings class. My program is suppose to write an array of the bankaccount object to the hard drive, and read it when the program launches. The reason I have an array is so I can hold up to three accounts of checking and savings that are identified by an ID that is asked for from the user. My question is if I have an id field, and a balance field in each checking/savings classes. How do I identify which of those ids is located at what array reference. And if this question makes no sense I apologize. I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have an array of BankAccount. If you want to find the BankAccount for a certain id, then you'd iterate through the array with a for loop, and inside the loop you'd check if the id of the BankAccount at that index matches the desired id. For example, assuming an array called `bankAccounts`, then you could loop through it ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < bankAccounts.length; i++) {
  if (bankAccounts[i].getId() == desiredId) {
    // do something with this BankAccount
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> Im sorry new to this inheritance thing. If id is stored in checking, will bankaccounts[i].getid() get the id stored in checking?

That's the beauty of inheritance. Because CheckingAccount is a child of the BankAccount class, it gains all the public methods of BankAccount including its `getid()` method. So if BankAccount has this as a public method, then you can be assured that all of its children get the method too.

Comment: Im sorry new to this inheritance thing. If id is stored in checking, will bankaccounts[i].getid() get the id stored in checking?

Comment: or would I do something like bankAccounts[i].checking.getid()?

Comment: @user2733862 In that case `bankAccounts[i]` *would be* a `Checking` object instance. So `bankaccounts[i].getid()` would give the ID of a checking account.

Comment: @user2733862: Please see edit to answer. And no, you wouldn't do `bankAccounts[i].checking.getid()` as that is not valid Java.

Comment: @user2733862 As a note, if an answer is good enough to be accepted, it is usually good to give it an upvote as well.

Comment: So when I create an instance of a superclass i'm automatically making an instance of its subclasses?

Comment: @user2733862: be careful with terms super and sub. The CheckingAccount is the subclass, and BankAccount is the superclass, and so your statement above is false.

Comment: So lets say I want to set the ID field in checking at the array reference 0. Would I just say 
    Bankaccount[0] checking = new Checking();
    checking.id = ID;

Comment: Nvm I just answered my own question bankaccounts[i].setid() ... duh thank you everyone for your help

Comment: @user2733862: there you go!

Comment: Ok so I have one final question. If bankAccount[i] is a Checking object instance because its a subclass and Savings is an object instance and they both have a field of ID how does it know which one we're talking about. Or is it a uniform situation where checking and savings will have the same Id, because in a real life scenario a checking and savings would be tied to one account number?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @user2733862 `bankAccount[i]`, being an instance of either `BankAccount` or a class deriving from it, exposes behaviours and properties that belong to a bank account. We should not need to know what specific type of account it is, and type specific behaviours can be implemented via method overriding.